# Python library for detecting a shape and calculating its area

Tags: python, image-processing

I am working on a project where I have pictures of shapes (animals from above) and I want to

1. detect the shapes
2. measure their area taking into account the angle of the camera

Anyone have any suggestions about how to do that, and are there some python libraries that might be useful?

Comment: `OpenCV` and/or `scikit-image` .... ?

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It the shapes are well contrasted and of a distinct color than the background, you will used segmentation functions. But you can't measure the area of a 3D object from a single image.

Comment: you want to look for unique features that can identify your shape of interest. Does it have a well defined edge? then look into edge detection. Is it a solid blob of a consistent color? look into connected component labeling. Once you have a more solid idea of what you need to do with the images, come back to us with any questions you have on implementation.